# i want to slide images ,images are coming through json

Tags: android, json, slider, android-volley

i want to slide images ,images are coming through json . Using of this code it is coming in list view . But i want all ten images should come as a slider .How van i do this?

I want to slide image one by one in horizontal.

i am getting like this image

see in the image .

[image]

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String url = "http://20dde605.ngrok.io/api/v1/restaurants/get_featured_restaurants";
    // Movies json url
    //private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
        // changing action bar color
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));
        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                //movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                //movie.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                //movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("org_image_url"));
                                //movie.setAverage_ratings(obj.getString("average_ratings"));
                                //movie.setCuisine(obj.getString("cuisine"));
                                //movie.setAddress(obj.getJSONObject("address").getString("area"));
                                //movie.setAddress(obj.getString("address"));
                                //movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));
                                // Genre is json array
                                /*JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);*/
                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        hidePDialog();

                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Appcontroller.java

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

model -movie

```
public class Movie {
    private String name, thumbnailUrl;
    //private int year;
    private String average_ratings,area,cuisine,address;
//  private ArrayList<String> genre;

    public Movie() {
    }

    public Movie(String name, String thumbnailUrl, String average_ratings,String area,String cuisine,String address
            ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
        //this.year = year;
        this.average_ratings = average_ratings;
        this.area=area;
        this.cuisine=cuisine;
this.address=address;
        //this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getThumbnailUrl() {
        return thumbnailUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
    }

    /*public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }*/

    /*public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }*/

    public String getAverage_ratings() {
        return average_ratings;
    }

    public void setAverage_ratings(String average_ratings) {
        this.average_ratings = average_ratings;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCuisine() {
        return cuisine;
    }

    public void setCuisine(String cuisine) {
        this.cuisine = cuisine;
    }
    /*public ArrayList<String> getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(ArrayList<String> genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }
*/
}
```

LruBitmapcache

```
public class LruBitmapCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements
        ImageCache {
    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

        return cacheSize;
    }

    public LruBitmapCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public LruBitmapCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<ViewFlipper>` or `<ViewPager>` or use [ImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) library.

Answer (score 0):

I better suggest to use pager for the slideshow. For you reference: [to use pager](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager/)
For another thing we can even use timer:

```
  public void makescroll() {
       final Handler mHandler= new Handler();

        // Create runnable for posting
        final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                AnimateandSlideShow(); //display image of your arraylist

            }
        };
        int delay = 5000; // delay for 1 sec.

        int period = 5000; // repeat every 4 sec.

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {

                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

            }

        }, delay, period);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `RecyclerView` over normal `ListView` for better performance and more customizable.
`RecyclerView` support horizontal lists but setting `LinearLayoutManager` as follows:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```